# solve $x^2 = 9 \pmod {100}$

Tags: number-theory

solve $x^2 = 9 \pmod {100}$

Obviously $+- 3 \pmod {100}$ work, but how do i know these are the only ones? tonnellis algorithm only works if p is prime and 100 is obviously not a prime number.... Is the Euclidian alghoritm an option?

Kees

Comment: You can try solving $(x+3)(x-3) \equiv 0 $ mod $100$. So you would look for when $x+3 \equiv 0$, $x-3 \equiv 0$ and $yz\equiv 0$ ($x+3=y$  and $x-3=z$).

Comment: Hint: Use [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to solve it mod $4$ and mod $25$.

Comment: @vadim kind of sucks doing mod 25 though.....

Comment: It's still easier mod 25 than mod 100.

Comment: If you don't want to square 25 numbers (really only 13), you can use [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma), which is about the same amount of work.

Comment: i already did the squares and i got that x must be the following:

x = 1 mod 4 or 3 mod 3:

x = 3 mod 25 or -3 mod 25

Comment: For $n>9$ two solutions of $x^2\equiv 9 \pmod n$ are  $\pm 3 \pmod n$

Comment: Any $x\equiv+3\pmod{100}$ will work, and any $x\equiv-3\pmod{100}$ will work, hence any number ending with $03$ or $97$ will work.

Comment: @gammatester Is that true? What about $n=40$ and $x=7$?

Comment: @Trevor Norton: Yes, because $(\pm 3)^2 = 9$  and if you reduce mod  $n$ this will stay $\equiv 9$. But there may be more solutions if $n$ is not prime.

Comment: @gammatester Oh okay. I thought you meant that those were the only solutions.

Comment: i solved it using the chinese remainder theorem thanks guys :)

Comment: @KeesTil You should get $4$ solutions mod $100$ given by Chinese Remainder Theorem by the congruences $x\equiv \pm 3\pmod{25}$, $x\equiv \pm 3\pmod{4}$.

Comment: @KeesTil You probably have a typo in one of your comments: it should be  3 mod 4, not mod 3.

Answer (score 2):

Solving the congruence $x^{2}\equiv 9\pmod {100}$ is equivalent to finding integers satisfying the following two congruences
$$x^{2}\equiv 9\equiv 1\pmod {4}~~~\text{and}~~~x^{2}\equiv 9\pmod {25}$$
simultaneously.
By inspection, we see that the first congruence have two solutions
$$x\equiv 1\pmod {4}~~~\text{and}~~~x\equiv 3\pmod {4}.$$
Now we solve the second congruence. Note first that an integer satisfying the second congruence satisfy the congruence
$$x^{2}\equiv 4\pmod {5}.$$
One can easily see that this congruence has two solutions
$$x\equiv 2\pmod {5}~~~\text{and}~~~x\equiv 3\pmod {5}.$$
Write $x=5k+2$. Then $x^{2}=25k^{2}+20k+4$ and so
$$x^{2}\equiv 9\pmod {25}\Leftrightarrow 4k\equiv 1\pmod {5}\Leftrightarrow k\equiv 4\pmod {5}.$$
Thus, $x\equiv 22\pmod {25}$ is a solution to the congruence $x^{2}\equiv 9 \pmod {25}$. Similarly, we can see that $x\equiv 3\pmod {25}$ is another solution.
It remains to solve four systems of linear congruences:
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 1\pmod {4}\\
x\equiv 3\pmod {25}
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 1\pmod {4}\\
x\equiv 22\pmod {25}
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 3\pmod {4}\\
x\equiv 3\pmod {25}
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
x\equiv 3\pmod {4}\\
x\equiv 22\pmod {25}
\end{cases}
Solution of each system of linear congruence gives a solution to the original congruence
$$x^{2}\equiv 9\pmod {100}.$$
Solving these four linear congruences using the Chinese remainder theorem, we have four solutions $x\equiv 3,47,53,97 \pmod {100}$.

Comment: Somewhat more generally, consider $x^2 \equiv a^2 \mod p^m$, i.e. $(x-a)(x+a) \equiv 0 \mod p^m$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $\gcd(a,p) = 1$.  Note that $2a = (x+a) - (x-a)$, so $x-a$ and $x+a$ can't both be divisible by $p$.  Thus the only solutions are $x \equiv \pm a \mod p^m$.

Comment: You're right. You observed that in our case the equation can be factored into linear factors easily. I think your answer is much much much better than mine!

Comment: $x^{2}\equiv 9\pmod {25}\Leftrightarrow 4k\equiv 1\pmod {5}\Leftrightarrow k\equiv 4\pmod {4}.$.  Um doesn't $4*8 \equiv 2\pmod{5}$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that requires very little theory beyond the basics of integer factorization.

You need to solve the equation
$$(x-3)(x+3) \equiv 0 \pmod {100}$$
Interpret this equation this way:  $x-3$ and $x+3$ are two numbers that differ by $6$, and whose product is a multiple of $100$.  We need to find two such numbers.

Now the two numbers, multiplied together, must have at least two factors of $5$ and two factors of $2$ (because any multiple of $100$ must contain all of those).  Because our two unknown numbers differ by exactly $6$, the two factors of $5$ can't be split between the two unknown numbers (if one of them is a multiple of $5$, the other one can't be).  So one of the two unknowns must be a multiple of $25$ -- which means it is $25,50$ or $75$.  (I'm ignoring the trivial case where one of the numbers is $0$, because that corresponds to the solutions $x = \pm 3$, which you already know about.)

But if one of the numbers is $25$, then the other number is $25 \pm 6$, in which case they are both odd -- and we need to get our two factors of $2$ from *somewhere*, so that possibility is ruled out.  For the same reason, we can rule out the possibility that one of the numbers is $75$.

So we are down to only one possibility:  One of the numbers is $50$, and the other number is either $44$ or $56$.  Notice that either of these two cases will work:
$$ 44 \cdot 50 \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$$
and
$$ 50 \cdot 56 \equiv 0 \pmod{100}$$

These two possibilities correspond to the solutions $x =47$ and $x=53$, respectively.